# Node.js EJS template: how can I remove the port number from the href?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have the below code. I would like to print out the file names in that directory and append an href tag. The below code works but only the port number my node.js app is listening to is still there. How could I remove that (so my hrefs will actually work?). Something with the document object, as in truncating the URL?

```
<h1><%= title %></h1>
<p>Welcome to
    <%=t itle %>
</p>
<ul>
    <% for(var i=0; i<fs.readdirSync( './Week4/').length; i++) {%>
        <li>
            <a href="<%= fs.readdirSync('./Week4/')[i] %>">
                <%=f s.readdirSync( './Week4/')[i] %>
            </a>
        </li>
        <% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question. Could you, please, provide an example of the current output and an example of the expected one, please ?

Comment: The current output says if I click on one of the list items: domain:8080/week4/listitem. I want to remove the :'8080', because this is why the file is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

From reading your comments, it seems that your problem is not where you think it is.
The `:8080` you see is written automatically because you specify an href that is relative to the current URL:

If the current URL is `localhost:8080/Week4/index.html`, going to the relative URL `itemlist` will in fact redirect you to `localhost:8080/Week4/itemlist`.

If this is not the way you intend things to work, you have to specify an absolute URL. For instance, using `//localhost:80/Week4/itemlist` will redirect you to another server (or another listener on the same server).

---

I don't exactly know what you are trying to achieve but, to me, the behavior you are expecting doesn't sound really good. A link should not redirect to a different port on the same server except if you are doing something very specific.

If you could tell us what you are **really** trying to achieve, we could help you better.

Comment: I want to href each list item so it takes me directly to the specific file that I click on.

Comment: Sorry but that is not precise enough. Do you have a route serving those files ? Why do you expect to see them without the port ?

Comment: Oddly enough, if I navigate to the file on port 8080 (that my express JS is using) I get a 404: Error: Not Found
    at /var/www/richarddemeny/myapp/app.js:30:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/richarddemeny/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/var/www/richarddemeny/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13) - with a few more lines of similar error messages. If I navigate to it without the port, the file serves up without a problem.